# Redirect from one directory to another

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On our old site, we had a folder called /images/daily with several images inside it.

Now we have redone our site, and the folder is called '/img/daytime' with the same images inside it.

How can I set up my .htaccess file to redirect all requests to /images/daily to the new folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^images/daily/(.+)$ /img/daytime/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```